# Assign tasks to Document Library Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, library, task-list

I started a task list to track ACTIVE document expiration dates
- Doc Name
- Doc Type
- Expiration Date
- Review Date
- Assigned To

I wanted to create a sub-folder for the obsolete stuff, but that would take too much time to post 1x1 with all of the details.

A doc library lets be dump the old stuff, but bossman wants it one place (folder>sub-folder)

A library lets me dump files and I can add the needed columns above, but how to have the columns link to a task list?

Flexibility/Speed of a library with the details/columns of a list and function of a task.

Comment: Can you tell us which version (2010, 2013) and edition (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise) you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways that you can handle this sort of scenario. Since you have said that your boss would like these to all be handles in one place I'll give you the simplest suggestion I can think of. Once I know the version/edition of SharePoint you are using I might amend this suggestion, though.

You can create a custom content type that has the columns you require added to it.

Your fist step is going to be creating the site columns that you require.

- [How to create site columns in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointnoob.com/2012/03/29/howto-create-site-column-sharepoint-2010/)
- [SharePoint 2010 Lesson 6 Document Management Site Columns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFC04PGwK9A)

Then create the custom content type adding the site columns you have created.

- [Introduction to content types and content type publishing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-HA101631493.aspx)
- [Creating a Content Type in SharePoint 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA9t0smteGI)

Comment: Is it one "task" per document? Still need clarity around SP version and edition.

Comment: Office 365 online.

Comment: Each doc has it's own due date/task. I added the existing site columns - Due Date, % complete, and Assigned To thinking that if these are here that the item is then linked to the tasks list these are from.  Didn't work.  Do I need to create new columns that duplicate the existing ones used for tasks and then add them to a custom Content Type?